# O que são os blocos Try/Catch?

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

Gostaria de saber o que são os blocos `try...catch`.

Gostaria de mais informações em português, porque em inglês eu não entendi muita coisa, somente que seria uma espécie de `if...else`.

- O que são esses blocos `try...catch`?
- Quando tenho que utilizá-los?
- Sempre (deveria) usar eles quando tenho uma consulta SQL?

<sup>Talvez alguns exemplos ajudem a compreender melhor</sup>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para entender o bloco `try/catch` é necessário compreender o conceito de exceção. Não se assuste, é bem comum que este conceito cause estranheza quando você começa a estudar o paradigma de orientação à objetos.

#### Exceção

Na ciência da computação, exceção é um objeto que define um fluxo alternativo à execução normal do programa. Isso acontece quando algumas condições em parte do programa não são satisfeitas, mas que podem ser tratadas, por isso a expressão tratamento de exceções. É bastante utilizada quando for desenvolver bibliotecas reutilizáveis, em que a lógica de negócio implementada não pode ser tão rígida, pois ficaria preso a uma aplicação apenas.

Imagine que você tenha uma função que efetua a raiz quadrada de um número. O código seria semelhante a isso:

```
function sqrt ($number)
{
  // Calcula a raiz quadrada
  return $result;
}
```

Porém, considerando apenas números reais, a função só funcionará corretamente se o parâmetro de entrada for um valor não-negativo. Desta forma, se o parâmetro for negativo, você deve criar um fluxo alternativo para o programa através de uma exceção.

```
function sqrt ($number)
{
  if ($number < 0)
  {
    throw new \Exception("$number must be a non-negative number");
  }

  // Calcula a raiz quadrada
  return $result;
}
```

Desta forma, ao tentar calcular a raiz quadrada de um número negativo, teríamos:

```
> sqrt(-1);
Uncaught Exception: -1 must be a non-negative number ...
```

#### Tratamento de exceção

Com o bloco `try/catch` você tem a liberdade para decidir qual será o novo fluxo do programa. Neste exemplo, digamos que se o valor de entrada for negativo, eu desejo calcular a raiz quadrada do mesmo valor, porém positivo, emitindo um *warning* para o usuário. Poderiámos fazer algo como:

```
$value = -4;

try {
    $result = sqrt($value);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    log($e->getMessage());
    $value *= -1; // Inverte o valor de $value
    $result = sqrt($value);
    warning("$value era negativo, então seu sinal foi alterado");
}

// Continuo com minha aplicação, onde $result = 2...
```

Sendo `$e` uma instância de `Exception`, o método `getMessage` retornará a mensagem de erro difinida na hora de seu disparo. Nesse caso, seria armazenado no *log* do sistema a mensagem *$number must be a non-negative number*.

#### Seu exemplo

Utilizando a biblioteca `PDO` para a conexão com o banco de dados, podemos ver na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.construct.php) que o construtor da classe dispara uma exceção do tipo `PDOException` caso a conexão falhar. Portanto, fazendo:

<sub>Colaboração de [@bonifazio](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/125288/bonifazio)</sub>

```
try{
  $pdo = new PDO(...);
  $pdo->setAttribute(...);
  ...
}catch(PDOException $e){
  // Omite a mensagem de erro para o cliente, só informando que houve um erro interno e salva o erro no log
  log($e->getMessage());
  http_response_code(500);
  die("Ooops! Algo errado não está certo. Por favor, volte mais tarde.");
}
```

Você garante que na linha `$pdo->setAtributte` a variável `$pdo` seja uma instância de `PDO` com a conexão ativa, pois, caso a conxeão falhe, o rumo do programa é alterado para o bloco `catch`. Sem a utilização dos blocos `try/catch` você não tem essa garantia. Se a conexão não for bem sucedida, é emitido o código 500 de resposta HTTP, informando um erro interno, mostrando, também, a mensagem ao usuário (considerando que a conexão com o banco seja trivial para o funcionamento do sistema, que é o que geralmente ocorre).

Você pode se perguntar: mas basta eu colocar um `if` ali que consigo a mesma garantia. Consegue, mas imagina que você esteja utilizando uma biblioteca de terceiro na sua aplicação. Se um erro assim acontecer, não é uma boa prática que você edite o código fonte diretamente, alterando-o para a sua aplicação. Se a biblioteca foi bem feita, ela disparará a exceção quando situações assim ocorrer e você capturando-as consegue fazer o tratamento sem alterar o código.

Answer (score 1):

Um bloco “try” é chamado de bloco “protegido” porque, caso ocorra algum problema com os comandos dentro do bloco, a execução desviará para os blocos “catch” correspondentes.

isso é, caso o código que esteja dentro do try contenha erro (não erro de lógica e sim de sintaxe), ele cairá no catch onde você pode tratar a exception.

Comment: Achei meio rala a explicação, o `try` `catch` cria uma estrutura onde o erro sera tratado como uma exceção e não um erro(essa exceção pode ser salva em um log, por exemplo, onde somente o desenvolvedor terá acesso, e poderá corrigir o erro), o código pode continuar a execução sem nenhum problema, coisa que normalmente não ocorreria sem o bloco `try` `catch`

Comment: Exceção capturando erro de sintaxe? Tem certeza disso?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss talvés não sobe me explicar direito, erros de sintexe o próprio compilador encontra, mas existem erros em bibliotecas que utiliza que o compilador não encontra, e quando ocorre esse tipo de erro ao usar o try catch ele cairá no catch.