# Não consigo encontrar o erro do Login

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, login

estou fazendo login, porém mesmo quando eu coloco os dados de um usuario cadastrado aparece dados inválidos.

login.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once "Classes/UsuariosDAO.php";
require_once "Classes/UsuariosVO.php";

$objUsuario= new UsuariosVO();
$objBDUsuario= new UsuariosDAO();

$email=$_POST['HTML_email_USUARIO'];
$senha= md5($_POST['HTML_senha_USUARIO']);


$tmpLogin=$objBDUsuario->loginUsuario($email, $senha);

if($tmpLogin==null){
//dados invalidos
echo 'Dados Inválidos';

 }else{
$objUsuario=$tmpLogin;

$_SESSION['email']=$objUsuario->getEmail();
$_SESSION['nome']=$objUsuario->getNome();
$_SESSION['status']= true;
$_SESSION['msg']= "Olá, ". $_SESSION['nome']."!"; 

$rsDados=$objBDUsuario->permissaoUsuario($permissao);
$tblDados= mysql_fetch_array($rsDados);

header("location:Home.php");
}
```

UsuariosDAO

```
function loginUsuario($tmpEmail, $tmpSenha){

$objBDpi = new BancoDAO();
    $objBDpi->AbreConexao();


$sqlLogin="Select * from usuarios where ";
$sqlLogin.="email_USUARIO like '$tmpEmail' ";
$sqlLogin.=" and ";
$sqlLogin.="senha_USUARIO like '$tmpSenha'";

 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');

$rsLogin= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlLogin) or die($mysqli_error($mysqli));

if(mysqli_num_rows($rsLogin)>0){ 

    $tblLogin= mysqli_fetch_array($rsLogin);

    $tmpUsuario=new UsuariosVO();

    $tmpUsuario->setEmail($tblLogin['email_USUARIO']);
    $tmpUsuario->setNome($tblLogin['nome_USUARIO']);

    return $tmpUsuario;


}else{
   return null;

}
}
```

UsuariosVO.php

```
<?php
class UsuariosVO{
public $nome, $senha, $email;

function _construct(){
    $this->setNome("");
    $this->setSenha("");
    $this->setEmail("");

}
public function getNome() {
    return $this->nome;
}

public function getSenha() {
    return $this->senha;
}

public function getEmail() {
    return $this->email;
}


public function setNome($tmpNome) {
    $this->nome = $tmpNome;
}

public function setSenha($tmpSenha) {
    $this->senha = $tmpSenha;
}

public function setEmail($tmpEmail) {
    $this->email = $tmpEmail;
}




}
?>
```

BancoDAO.php

```
<?php

 class BancoDAO {
     public $usuario="root", $senha="";
     public $servidor="localhost", $banco="bdpi";



     function AbreConexao(){
         $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');
         mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,'UTF-8');
        // Verifica se ocorreu algum erro
     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       die('Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados: ' .    mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
     }
     }

        function FechaConexao(){
          mysqli_close();
      }
  }
```

descobri que o erro está entre essas linhas:

```
 $rsLogin= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlLogin) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); if(mysqli_num_rows($rsLogin)>0){ tenho certeza.
```

Pq se eu modificar para (mysqli_num_rows($rsLogin)==0 
e colocar um echo "Deu ruim" no lugar de:

```
        $objUsuario=$tmpLogin; $_SESSION['email']=$objUsuario->getEmail(); $_SESSION['nome']=$objUsuario->getNome(); $_SESSION['status']= true; $_SESSION['msg']= "Olá, ". $_SESSION['nome']."!"; header("location:Home.php");
```

aparece o echo "Deu ruim"

Comment: Já tentou utilizar um try catch para obter a exception do possível problema?

Comment: Não tentei, como eu faço isso?

Comment: Esses links podem ajudar: [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58536/66203) e [O que são os blocos Try/Catch?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188499/66203) com Try/Catch. Só uma pergunta, sua senha está registrada no banco com criptografia MD5?

Comment: obrigado, vou dar uma olhada. Sim a senha está salva no banco em MD5

Comment: Você não teria que dar um return dentro do if ao invés de echo em UsuarioDAO?, ao invés de echo $tmpUsuario; fazer return $tmpUsuario; ?

Comment: mesmo assim não foi...E não consigo encontrar o erro. Mesmo que o usuario esteja cadastrado ainda vai aparecer dados invalidos. O que será?

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código de `BancoDAO`

Comment: coloquei o código

Comment: Já tentou dar um `echo $tmpEmail.' - '.$tmpSenha;` para saber se os valores estão sendo recebidos ? Tente alterar `$sqlLogin.="email_USUARIO like '$tmpEmail' ";` e `$sqlLogin.="senha_USUARIO like '$tmpSenha'";` para `$sqlLogin.="email_USUARIO = '$tmpEmail' ";` e `$sqlLogin.="senha_USUARIO ='$tmpSenha'";`

Comment: Já tentei, não mudou nada

Answer (score 0):

No comando abaixo você tem que colocar um return no lugar do echo.

Ficando da seguinte forma:

```
if($rsLogin->num_rows > 0){ 

$tblLogin= mysqli_fetch_array($rsLogin);

$tmpUsuario=new UsuariosVO();

$tmpUsuario->setEmail($tblLogin['email_USUARIO']);
$tmpUsuario->setNome($tblLogin['nome_USUARIO']);

return $tmpUsuario;
```

}

Substitua também o seu método loginUsuario pelo abaixo.

```
function loginUsuario($tmpEmail, $tmpSenha){

$objBDpi = new BancoDAO();
    $objBDpi->AbreConexao();


$sqlLogin="Select * from usuarios where ";
$sqlLogin.="email_USUARIO like '$tmpEmail' ";
$sqlLogin.=" and ";
$sqlLogin.="senha_USUARIO like '$tmpSenha'";

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    die();

$rsLogin= $mysqli->query($sqlLogin);

if($rsLogin->num_rows > 0){ 

    $tblLogin= mysqli_fetch_array($rsLogin);

    $tmpUsuario=new UsuariosVO();

    $tmpUsuario->setEmail($tblLogin['email_USUARIO']);
    $tmpUsuario->setNome($tblLogin['nome_USUARIO']);

    return $tmpUsuario;


}else{
   return null;

}
}
```

Comment: mesmo assim não foi...E não consigo encontrar o erro. Mesmo que o usuario esteja cadastrado ainda vai aparecer dados invalidos. O que será?

Comment: Tente substituir a sua SQL colocando da seguinte forma:

$sqlLogin="Select * from usuarios where ";
$sqlLogin.="email_USUARIO = '$tmpEmail' ";
$sqlLogin.=" and ";
$sqlLogin.="senha_USUARIO = '$tmpSenha'";

Comment: não adiantou :/ Será que é algum erro no banco?

Comment: @fer Fiz o teste na minha máquina rodando o seu script e rodou perfeito sem problema nenhum.  Como teste você pode fazer o seguinte, onde você pega os valores vindo via POST do html coloque as informações que você tem no seu banco, no meu caso eu coloquei dessa forma $email='teste@teste.com'; e $senha= md5('teste');. As vezes não é um problema do código PHP em si pode ser a forma em que você está enviado esses dados via HTML. Me informa qual o resultado quando você testar.

Comment: Então o que será?

Comment: Editei a mensagem acima, confere de novo por favor.

Comment: Ainda aparece dados invalidos

Comment: Como estão os dados no banco de dados? A senha criptografada está certa? Tente colocar essa senha no seu banco 698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b e na variável da senha você coloca teste. Verifique se vai passar. Outra coisa, comente as linhas //$objBDpi = new BancoDAO();
  //  $objBDpi->AbreConexao();

Comment: estão criptografadas

Comment: realmente está criptografada

Comment: Qual foi o resultado? Deu Dados Inválidos de novo?

Comment: simm, oque será que há de errado?

Comment: Bom muito estranho, tente fazer o seguinte: Coloque um var_dump($mysqli); logo após a variável $mysqli e outro var_dump($rsLogin); logo após a variável $rsLogin). Me fale qual será o retorno desses dois var_dump.

Comment: quando você testou na sua máquina, você copio exatamente oq ta escrito na pergunta?

Comment: Sim foi a mesma coisa, a única coisa que troquei foi o o echo, substitui pelo return conforme lhe falei. Outra coisa eu comentei as linhas //$objBDpi = new BancoDAO();
  //  $objBDpi->AbreConexao(); e //$rsDados=$objBDUsuario->permissaoUsuario($permissao);

Comment: até o $tmpEmail está tudo correto. Depois ou a tela aparece em branco ou aparece dados invallidos

Comment: tentei fazer oq vc fez mas continua a mesma coisa

Comment: O erro está em uma dessas linhas: $rsLogin= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlLogin) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($rsLogin)>0){  tenho certeza. Pq se eu modificar para ==0 e colocar um echo no lugar de: $objUsuario=$tmpLogin;
    
    $_SESSION['email']=$objUsuario->getEmail();
    $_SESSION['nome']=$objUsuario->getNome();
    $_SESSION['status']= true;
    $_SESSION['msg']= "Olá, ". $_SESSION['nome']."!"; 
        

          header("location:Home.php"); aparece o echo

Comment: Eu editei a minha resposta tente fazer da forma que coloquei agora e me fale o resultado.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::connect_errno() in